# Are there $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ Kernels?

Tags: machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Some kernels used in machine learning are linked to metrics via the negative exponential function $f(t) = e^{-t^p}$. The most prominent example is the Gaussian RBF kernel
$$K(x,y) = e^{-\sigma^2 \|x-y\|_2^2}$$
The connection between metrics and PD kernels was also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221704/transforming-a-distance-function-to-a-kernel?noredirect=1&lq=1). Furthermore, it was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885462/is-the-exponential-of-d-a-positive-definite-kernel-for-a-general-metric-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $$K(x,y) = e^{-\|x-y\|_{\infty}}$$ is not PD. However, I am wondering whether there are other ways to connect the maximum norm with some function $f$ such that $f(\|x-y\|_{\infty})$ is actually a PD kernel on $\mathbb{R}^d$.